# Adding Oracle Remote Introdoc Cleint dependencies in maven pom.xml

Tags: maven, oracle-ucm

I am unable to download Oracle RIDC client dependencies using maven. I added below code in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.oracle.ucm</groupId>
<artifactId>ridc</artifactId>
<version>11.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

my question is do I need to add any plugins or it is not possible to download the ridc dependencies using maven

Comment: What do you mean by `I am unable to download ...`? Error message? Logged in cause it seemed to be an oracle artifact?

Answer (score 2):

Oracle dependencies are typically not available in the public maven repo. To go about this you can do a few things.

- Install the item locally in your repo. Using this `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path>
    -DgroupId=<group> -DartifactId=<id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=jar`
- If you have a local repo like nexus, artifactory, you can install it in there.
- Or you can mark that dependency as provided and make sure your runtime has it in place.

Answer (score 2):

From my [Maven repo](https://bintray.com/jhult/maven/oracle.ucm%3Aridc):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation='http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd'
          xmlns='http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                    <id>bintray-jhult-maven</id>
                    <name>bintray</name>
                    <url>https://dl.bintray.com/jhult/maven</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                    <id>bintray-jhult-maven</id>
                    <name>bintray-plugins</name>
                    <url>https://dl.bintray.com/jhult/maven</url>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
            <id>bintray</id>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>bintray</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```